# Caching React components with service worker

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

I was thinking of creating React PWA recently. My plan was to have nice React component that will be cached in the service worker and it will be served by it when there is no internet connection..... But when I started to implement it....
I really don't how to do it! If anybody know how to do it, please help me on this topic! Thanks in advance!!!

> I mainly want to use React because of its many benefits(Component based file structure, easy state management etc.).

Answer (score 1):

There is a great talk by **Zack Argyle** ,Enigneering Manager of Pinterest, about **OFFLINE REACT** on React Rally 2017. You could get basic understanding from there.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f4KnHNCZcH4

Further `webpack 4` has updated their docs and included service workers in PWA section. Please have a look on this:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/progressive-web-application/#registering-our-service-worker

Comment: I will look at it after I am free if it helps I will check your answer!